ESP-C3 Super mini MAX98357A and SD Card Reader together
After a lot of research and minimum results about pin mapping and particular specific configurations for SPI and I2S on ESP-C3, i about to give up on this.
I have recently bought ESP32-C3 Supermini because of its size and versatility, but i'm facing some trouble to make my code work correctly.

WHen i try to start I2S to initialise my MAX98357A, my SD card stop reading files.
What i have for now:
//    SD Card
#define SD_SCK 1
#define SD_MISO 0
#define SD_MOSI 4
#define SD_SS 5                  // Chip Select

//    I2S
#define I2S_DOUT 6  // GPIO2 (DIN) 2
#define I2S_BCLK 7  // GPIO21 (BCLK) 21
#define I2S_LRC  8  // GPIO3 (LRC) 3
#define I2S_NUM       0          // i2s port number

SPIClass spi(FSPI); //HSPI FSPI

 static const i2s_config_t i2s_config = 
      {
          .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
          .sample_rate = 44100,                                 // Note, all files must be this
          .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
          .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
          .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S | I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB),
          .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,             // high interrupt priority
          .dma_buf_count = 8,                                   // 8 buffers
          .dma_buf_len = 256,                                   // 256 bytes per buffer, so 2K of buffer space
          .use_apll=0,
          .tx_desc_auto_clear= true, 
          .fixed_mclk=-1    
      };
      
      // These are the physical wiring connections to our I2S decoder board/chip from the esp32, there are other connections
      // required for the chips mentioned at the top (but not to the ESP32), please visit the page mentioned at the top for
      // further information regarding these other connections.
      
      static const i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = 
      {
          .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK,                           // The bit clock connectiom, goes to pin 27 of ESP32
          .ws_io_num = I2S_LRC,                             // Word select, also known as word select or left right clock
          .data_out_num = I2S_DOUT,                         // Data out from the ESP32, connect to DIN on 38357A
          .data_in_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE                  // we are not interested in I2S data into the ESP32
      };

void setup() {
    spi.begin(SD_SCK, SD_MISO, SD_MOSI, SD_SS);
    pinMode(SD_SS, OUTPUT); 
    digitalWrite(SD_SS, HIGH); // SD card chips select, must use GPIO 5 (ESP32 SS)
    if(!SD.begin(SD_SS, spi))//SD_CS
    {
        Serial.println("Error starting SD!");
        while(true);                  
    }

    // SD Card fully works here

    i2s_driver_install(i2s_num, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_set_pin(i2s_num, &pin_config);

    // ...and now i just cant open files and directories anymore.

}

what i'm missing here?

Well, you may be confused about pin numbering schemes. But it's difficult to tell in what exact way. It would help to clearly see what your actual wiring is. If this code is (or is based on) an example a link to that may help.

this code is purely extracted from an example with different pins oon it., (the SD part) the I2S part is another code combined on it.
I achieved that pins configuration on trial and error.  and researching about behave of ESP32-C3 info on foruns across the internet.  but there is a lot of confusing information about pins and behave of them on C3 super mini.
So the physical wiring configuration is representated by what is in the code.

What exactly your chose as the board selection on your Arduino IDE (tools->board)? The pinmap picture you shown is for SeeedStudio XIAO-C3, so unless you had a XIAO-C3, supermini available in the market uses Espressif default C3 pin assignments. AND your code neither conforms to XIAO nor to Espressif C3 pinmap. So please clarify and provide your connection diagram...

The GPIO pins (marked green on your picture) match the GPIO pinout of the Superminis I have. In anycase, these are printed on the back silk screen.  You will compile using the ESP32C3 dev Module so you must look look at that board to match functions to GPIO pins. See https://mischianti.org/esp32-c3-devkitc-02-high-resolution-pinout-and-specs/. The comment about a fixed GPIO 5 seems strange and is probably intended for another board since SS is GPIO 7 by default on an ESP32C3.  Which ESP32 Arduino core are you using 2.x or 3.x. If 3.x try the latest 2.x instead.
